# Modifying MongoDB data in flask

Tags: python, mongodb, d3.js

I am running a flask server which fetched data from mongo DB.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from pymongo import Connection
import json
from bson import json_util
from bson.json_util import dumps

app = Flask(__name__)

MONGODB_HOST = 'localhost'
MONGODB_PORT = 27017
DBS_NAME = 'donorschoose'
COLLECTION_NAME = 'projects'
FIELDS = {'school_state': True, 'resource_type': True, 'poverty_level': True, 'date_posted': True, 'total_donations': True, '_id': False}

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/donorschoose/projects")
def donorschoose_projects():
    connection = Connection(MONGODB_HOST, MONGODB_PORT)
    collection = connection[DBS_NAME][COLLECTION_NAME]
    projects = collection.find(fields=FIELDS)
    json_projects = []
    for project in projects:
        json_projects.append(project)
    json_projects = json.dumps(json_projects, default=json_util.default)
    connection.disconnect()
    return json_projects

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=5000,debug=True)
```

I got this code from the net and implemented it successfully. And feeding data to d3 apps via this app. My question is: Is it possible to modify data right here in the flask environment using python? (in the code that i have pasted above?). I only ask because python would allow a greater deal of flexibility than d3 as my expertise in d3 is less. To the problem: The 'poverty-level' column will have 4 fixed values i.e. low, medium, high, unkown.
My aim is to calculate the percentage of high poverty level
 i.e. for the column'poverty_level' -> count(val =high)/count(all rows)

Essentially i need just one column to display my metric and i had a tough time doing this is d3. Any d3 or python level help will be much appreciated :)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to completely iterate the Cursor returned by find():

```
projects = list(collection.find(fields=FIELDS))
```

Then calculate the total number and the number of high-poverty projects:

```
high_poverty_count = len(p for p in projects if p['poverty_level'] == 'high')
high_poverty_ratio = float(high_poverty_count) / len(projects)
```

Then I'd add this together with the list of all projects, together as a document:

```
result = {'high_poverty_ratio': high_poverty_ratio,
          'projects': projects}

return json.dumps(result, default=json_util.default)
```

Also, note that your application has two severe problems:

First, you use "Connection", which is [obsolete](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/connection.html). Do this:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient(MONGODB_HOST, MONGODB_PORT)
```

Second, you create a new client and disconnect it for each request. This is extremely slow. Instead, create the client when your application begins, and never disconnect it:

```
client = MongoClient(MONGODB_HOST, MONGODB_PORT)

@app.route("/donorschoose/projects")
def donorschoose_projects():
    collection = client[DBS_NAME][COLLECTION_NAME]
    # ... etc ....
    return json.dumps(result, default=json_util.default)
```